# nginx configuration for a RESTful API

Tags: php, nginx

I am a beginner with nginx and php, so please excuse my basic question.

For a RESTful based API (nginx + php) I would need some help with nginx configuration.

Here is the relevant snippet of the nginx configuration (as suggested [here](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Proxy_Everything)) for redirecting all /api/v1/* requests to my apiv1.php script:

```
    server {
        server_name myServer;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        location /api/v1/ {
          try_files $uri $uri/ /apiv1.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }
```

Now the issue is that when I type http://myServer//api/v1/resource/GetInfo in my browser, the apiv1.php script doesn't seem to receive the "resource/GetInfo". Actually, _GET and _REQUEST are empty, but _SERVER looks OK!

In my /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini, the following relevant config is enabled:

```
request_order = "GP"
variables_order = "GPCS"
register_argc_argv = Off
auto_globals_jit = On.
```

Do you maybe know why the php _GET and _REQUEST are empty? Is this related to my php configuration only?

Best regards,
M.

Comment: [$args](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24args) only contains GET parameters (i.e. query strings). So in your example you would be appending the query strings (if any) to the fallback uri in your try_files directive.

Comment: Thanks, looks like I missed that one.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Replace this:

```
location /api/v1/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /apiv1.php?$args;
}
```

With the following inside your server block:

```
rewrite ^/api/v1/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /apiv1.php?class=$1&method=$2? last;
```

Create a php file called apiv1.php and place in the root directory of your web server with the following lines of code:

```
<?php
$class  = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'class',  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$method = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'method', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

echo $class;
echo '<br />';
echo $method;
```

Test by visiting the following link in your browser:

```
http://myServer/api/v1/members/getInfo
```

Comment: Great, now my _GET and _REQUEST are no longer empty :) Well, I'm one step forward because you helped me, so thanks a lot! :)

Comment: This is a good answer -- I initially got the common File not Found error PHP. Then I ran: tail /var/log/nginx/error.log and  "Unable to open primary script: /var/www/[myDomain]/html/apiv1.php -- so renamed index.php to apiv1.php and it worked.

Answer (score 5):

If someone else hit this page, there is solution I got for myself after a bit research:

```
location ~ ^/api/v0/(.*)/?$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /v0.php?req=$1&$args;
}
```

Here I'm not limited with class/method structure and location seems more readable than rewrite.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Good job. Concise, complete and useful.