# .htaccess rewrite cond and rule to nginx config

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting

I am trying to convert this apache .htaccess rule to something nginx can use.

This .htaccess is a part of this tutorial to make a php REST api. ( http://www.androidhive.info/2014/01/how-to-create-rest-api-for-android-app-using-php-slim-and-mysql-day-23/ )

The idea of this .htaccess file is to make a REST get/post request to "task_manager/v1/register/"
and it redirects you to "task_manager/v1/index.php"

.htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [QSA,L]
```

I've tried one idea from stackoverflow, one from winginx, and I tried writing one myself and they all sort of flop.

Nginx config:

something I tried and failed so I commented it out.

```
rewrite ^/task_manager/v1/(/)$ /task_manager/v1/index.php redirect;
```

something I saw in stackexchange and didn't help, so I commented it out

```
rewrite ^task_manager/api/v1/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ task_manager/api/v1/index.php?class=$1&method=$2? last;
```

was recommended to use winginx, didn't work. :c

```
location / {
if (!-e $request_filename){
rewrite ^(.*)$task_manager/v1/index.php break;
}
}
```

Please advise me.

Answer (score 1):

phew. Good thing I was *only* pretending to be dumb.

anyways, so yeah I was trying to make that android REST API work in nginx.

I took a look at another post ( [nginx configuration for a RESTful API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28094865/nginx-configuration-for-a-restful-api) )

and basically I just needed to change a few things.

original:

```
rewrite ^/api/v1/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /apiv1.php?class=$1&method=$2? last;
```

Edit:

```
rewrite ^/task_manager/v1/([^/]+)/?$ /task_manager/v1/index.php?method=$2? last;
```

It seems to work for this specific tutorial. I ran into a different problem with php5-fpm but at least when I use REST Client on chrome it either gives me a 500 error (logs show something in my config isn't parsed correctly) or it will tell me "no there are no users"/"no you are not logged in" but at least this part is solved.